# Mysql join two tables with sum of quantity

Tags: php, mysql

Q : I am trouble to do following task in `mysql` query.

Task is get all products *(If product is duplicate than **sum** of it's **qty**)* and deduct wastage stock *(If wastage product is duplicate than **sum** of it's **qty**)*.

I have two tables like,

> 1) manage_stock
>
> 2) manage_wastage

---

*manage_stock*

=> This table has `p_id`(Product ID) and many rows with product duplication's.

```
p_id p_name p_qty

1    Pro-1  10
2    Pro-2  15
3    Pro-3  8
1    Pro-1  15
```

---

*manage_wastage*

=> This table has `p_id`(Product ID) of *manage_stock* table. It is also many rows with product duplication's.

```
p_id w_qty

1    2
1    4
3    5
```

---

*Desired Output*

```
p_id p_name p_qty w_qty final_qty

1    Pro-1  20    6     14
2    Pro-2  15    0     15
3    Pro-3  8     5     3
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: `manage_wastage` table `p_id` primary key but your record repeat 1 two times

Answer (score 0):

You just have to compute the difference between the stock quantity and the wastage

```
 SELECT s.p_id, s.p_name, SUM(p_qty), SUM(w_qty), SUM(p_qty) - SUM(w_qty) as final_qty 
    FROM manage_stock s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN manage_wastage w
    ON s.p_id = w.p_id
    GROUP BY s.p_id, s.p_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ms.p_id ,GROUP_CONCAT(ms.p_name)p_name ,SUM(ms.p_qty) p_qty ,SUM(mw.w_qty) w_qty,SUM(ms.p_qty)-SUM(mw.w_qty) final_qty FROM manage_stock ms
INNER JOIN manage_wastage mw on ms.p_id =mw.p_id 
GROUP BY ms.p_id
```

Try above code.

As **`p_name`** always unique with p_id GROUP_CONCAT() only returns single name.

Comment: You can't select p_name because this column is not included in the group by clause nor in aggregate functions.

Comment: @tete0148 As **`p_name`** always unique with `p_id GROUP_CONCAT() `only returns single name.

Comment: Adding p_name in group by is correct too ? (I'm curious about that)

Comment: @tete yes it's also correct till pname is unique with p_id

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
SELECT s.p_id, s.p_name, SUM(p_qty),SUM(ifnull(w_qty, 0)),SUM(p_qty - ifnull(w_qty, 0)) as total
    FROM manage_stock s
    left outer JOIN manage_wastage w
    ON s.p_id = w.p_id 
    GROUP BY s.p_name
```

its work